# c# ConcurrentDictionary wrapping AddOrUpdate with lazy doesn't compile

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-evaluation, concurrentdictionary

I want to create a new class that will wrap the current .net ConcurrentDictionary so that the Add delegate of the GetOrAdd\AddOrUpdate will be ensured to be called only once. I've seen a couple of solutions on the net and the main one is to wrap the TValue with lazy so that many lazy items may be added but only one will survive and invoke it's value factory.

here is what I come up with:

```
public class LazyConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>> concurrentDictionary;

    public LazyConcurrentDictionary()
    {
        this.concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>();
    }

    public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
    {
        var lazyResult = this.concurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, k => new Lazy<TValue>(() => valueFactory(k), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication));

        return lazyResult.Value;
    }

    public TValue AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> addFactory, Func<TKey, TValue> updateFactory)
    {

        // this one fails with "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Lazy' because it is not a delegate type"
        var lazyResult = this.concurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, (k) => new Lazy<TValue>( () => addFactory(k), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication), updateFactory); 

        return lazyResult.Value;
    }
}
```

My issue is with the AddOrUpdate signature, I get "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Lazy' because it is not a delegate type"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missunderstood meaning of the updateFactory for this function. It is function from `TKey`,`TValue` to `TValue`, not from `TKey` to `TValue`, it should calculate an updated value from an old one. 
So  right syntax should perhaps be like:

```
public TValue AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> addFactory, 
                                    Func<TValue, TValue> updateFactory)
{
    var lazyResult = this.concurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key,
    (k) => new Lazy<TValue>(() => addFactory(k), 
                       LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication),
    (k,v)=>new Lazy<TValue>(()=>updateFactory(v.Value)))
    );

    return lazyResult.Value;
}
```

Or even (depending on how do you wnat to use it):

```
public TValue AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> addFactory, 
                                    Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateFactory)
{
    var lazyResult = this.concurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key,
    (k) => new Lazy<TValue>(() => addFactory(k), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication),
    (k,v)=>new Lazy<TValue>(()=>updateFactory(k, v.Value))
    );

    return lazyResult.Value;
}
```

Comment: of course, the compiler underlined the error under the add delegate so I've missed it, thanks Maksim!